# How do I get bold math with Linux Libertine in combination with ETbb (PdfLaTeX)?

Tags: fonts, math-fonts, newtxmath

The `ETbb` documentation suggests using `libertine` as the math companion for `ETbb`
and lists the following preamble as an example. I, however, can't get the bold non-italicized math symbols with this setup. I have tried the suggestions of related questions, but to no avail. Any suggestions?

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[p, osf]{ETbb}  % osf in text, tabular lining figures in math
\usepackage[scaled=.95,type1]{cabin}  % sans serif in style of Gill Sans
\usepackage[libertine, vvarbb]{newtxmath} % vvarbb was passed from newtx
\usepackage{bm}

\begin{document}
This equation is important:

\begin{equation}
        \mathbf{x}, \boldsymbol{x}, \mathrm{x}, \bm{\mathrm{x}}, x, y, \bm{\mathbf{x}}, \boldsymbol{x}
\end{equation}
\end{document}
```

[image]

---

edit: it's probably worth noting that the above code have been tested on Overleaf using the newest available distribution.

Comment: I can get bold roman "x" using `\textbf{x}`, though this might result in bad 'math mode' spacing (maybe)

Comment: Don't use `minimal` for a start. It is not intended for minimal examples and is especially unsuitable here.

Comment: The issue is the same without minimal, but thanks for the heads up.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `libertinust1math` package is compatible with `ETbb`:

```tex
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{libertinust1math}
\usepackage[p, osf]{ETbb}  % osf in text, tabular lining figures in math
\usepackage[scaled=.95,type1]{cabin}  % sans serif in style of Gill Sans
\usepackage{bm}

\begin{document}
This equation is important:

\begin{equation}
        \mathbf{x}, \boldsymbol{x}, \mathrm{x}, \bm{\mathrm{x}}, x, y, \bm{\mathbf{x}}, \boldsymbol{x}
\end{equation}
\end{document}
```

[image: ET Bembo + Libertinus T1 Math sample]

the incompatibility might be related to loading order; rearranging the packages can produce option clashes and missing font weights.

If you can use LuaLaTeX or XeLaTeX, ET Bembo, Libertinus Math and Cabin (or Gill Sans) are available in OTF.  Switching to Unicode cuts the Gordian knot of incompatibilities between all the different 8-bit font packages.

Comment: That seems to do the trick! I tried switching to LuaTex and XeTex, but there was to many issues that I did not want to fix. For my next project I will be starting with one of those hower! Also, thanks for using the term "Gordian knot", haven't heard that before :)